# Move JavaScript files to the bottom in Magento

Tags: javascript, magento

I see in the page.xml that the JavaScript files are set in the head like so:

```
<default>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-right.phtml">
        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs" ifconfig="dev/js/deprecation"><script>prototype/deprecation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs" ifconfig="dev/translate_inline/active"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/screen.css</stylesheet></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie8.css</name><params/><if>IE 8</if></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>varien/iehover-fix.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>

            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>
            <block type="page/html" name="store_language_js" as="store_language_js" template="page/html/head-translator.phtml"/>
</default>
```

But if I wanted to move them to the bottom would I just do the following?

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="unsetData">
        <name>items</name>
    </action><!– There are now no CSS/JavaScript links in the head –>

    <action method="addCss">
        <stylesheet>css/some-file.css</stylesheet>
    </action><!– There is now one CSS and no JavaScript links in the head –>
</reference>
```

And then in the `before_body_end` add back the JavaScript files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That method could work but would not be a good idea. There are many inline scripts throughout Magento that depend on the Javascript libraries being loaded in advance. Some modules add their own scripts for certain pages and if `items` were unset they would fail.

If your aim is to improve page load times then script concatenation - as provided by "Merge Javascript Files" setting, [Fooman Speedster](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/457/fooman-speedster) and previously mod_pagespeed (although the combine feature was buggy and removed) - will significantly reduce the round trip times of having scripts in the head.

To effectively move all script to the bottom you would need to override `Mage_Page_Block_Html` to filter all script tags then replace them before the `</body>` tag. The `before_body_end` block will already have been rendered by this point so you could not rely on that. I wouldn't want to try it as there is still much that could go wrong.

Comment: Ok I will the other suggestions a try instead of trying to move the external js to the bottom

Comment: it's a bit crap tho inline js?

Comment: Inline JS makes perfect sense if it is unique to a page or few pages, or if it changes often. Otherwise you are asking clients to download and execute some function all the time which is wasteful.

Comment: Just a pita to change it. Inline js never makes sense to me - it is a major flaw in magento in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento v1.6+ (need to test in older versions);

1 - create an template file in `page/html/footer/extras.phtml` with this content:

```
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
```

2 - Add this html node to your layout xml:

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
<block type="page/html_head" name="extra_js" as="extraJs" after="-" template="page/html/footer/extras.phtml">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.min.js</name></action>
</block>
```

3 - That is it!